# Solving $d\omega, \omega(X)$ , where $\omega$ is 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-forms

This is an attempt to solve problem 4.1 in Tu's *Introduction to manifolds*.

Given the 1-form $\omega = z dx - dz$ and the vector field $X = y \partial_x + x \partial_y$. Compute $\omega(X)$ and the exterior derivative $d\omega$.

\begin{align}
\omega(X) & = \sum a_I b_I \\
 & = zy - x \\ 
\end{align}
where $I = \{1, 2, 3\}$ is the multi-index and $a_I,b_I$ the function coeficients in $\omega, X$ respectively. Also
\begin{align}
d\omega & = (\sum da_I\wedge dx_I) \\
 & = \sum_I(\sum_j \partial_x^j a_I dx^j)\wedge dx_I \\ 
 & = d(z) \wedge dx + d(-1)\wedge dz \\
 & = (\partial_x z dx + \partial_y z dy + \partial_z z dz) \wedge dx + 0 \wedge dz\\
 & = 1 dz \wedge dx \\
 &= dz \wedge dx
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for $\omega(X)$ is incorrect. Note that $a_2 = 0$, $b_2 = x$, $a_3 = -1$ and $b_3 = 0$, so $\omega(X) = a_1b_1 = zy$.

Your expression for $d\omega$ is correct.

Comment: yes thanks, spot on. I messed up the multi-index. Should I edit answer or just leave as is?

Comment: I think just leave it as is.